Python requests retry adapter with multiple sequential requests
I have a class CustomSession. It behaves the same way as requests.Session, except calling the request method of this new class first makes a preliminary request prelim_request first using some pre-defined PRELIM_PARAMS, and then secondly makes a request request with user-provided parameters.
class CustomSession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.prelim_params = PRELIM_PARAMS

    def prelim_request(self):
        response = super().request(**self.prelim_params)

    def request(self, method, url, **kwargs):
        self.prelim_request()
        return super().request(method, url, **kwargs)

I want to implement some retry logic so that CustomSession.request is re-tried if the status_code of its output is either [502, 503, 504]. If I was just using the parent class requests.Session to make requests this would be done as follows:
retries = Retry(total=7, backoff_factor=1, status_forcelist=[502, 503, 504], allowed_methods=None)
session.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
session.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

But this only re-tries individual requests, i.e. if CustomSession.request outputs a response with status_code as 502 then only the second of the two requests within the method super().request(method, url, **kwargs) is retried, and NOT the entire CustomSession.request method itself (the two requests banded together).
I can probably resort to using try-except logic here but I would like to still use the Retry adapter if possible. How can I still make use of Retry here?

Can you share more about what the PRELIM_PARAMS are (or what the range of their values can be)? I'm assuming that the url that is part of them is different from the the url in the actual request, right? As far as I understand now, that is (or is part of) the underlying cause of the problem.

Please ignore my previous comment - it's irrelevant.

An HTTPAdapter acts on individual requests PreparedRequests. In your code you have a custom Session, but you are still using normal HTTPAdapter and Requests objects, so on that level nothing changes in the processing. In other words, when the first preliminary request fails (given the retry conditions), it will be retried. But when the second, "real" request fails, only that second one will be retried. The normal HTTPAdapter has no way to "go back in time", as it were; it doesn't know anything about earlier requests. The problem is that the requests retry logic is handled deep in the call stack:

the session delegates to the adapter
the adapter delegates to a connection, which it gets from a proxy-manager or pool-manager
the retry is then handled in the function urlopen of the connection

In your case, it seems you always want to retry on "bundled" requests (a preliminary plus an actual request). But the requests and urllib3 functions all assume "single" requests. I think you can say they are built around the core concept of a single URL. It's basically impossible to override the Request class, turning it into a container of requests. So, the only way I can think of to do what you want -- using only the requests and urllib3 libraries --, is to either handle the retry logic yourself (in the CustomSession.send method) or to use a regular Session with a custom HTTPAdapter. In the custom HTTPAdapter send method you would then still need to take full control over the retry logic, since for all the reasons stated above, you cannot really use the base HTTPAdapter class.
Of course there are also other alternatives, such as using the retrying library. But any of those also mean that you basically have to implement the retry logic yourself.

You could argue that this problem points to a design flaw in the requests library: the concept of Request and the concept to URL are very tightly coupled -- it's  practically impossible to separate them. But you could also argue against this, saying that that's just the basic usecase and opening this up would make the internals of the lib much more complex and not add any value for 99.9999% of  users.
